# How to stop showing ads after an AdClick? Which Ad Listener is better for this purpose, onAdClicked or onAdLeftApplication?

Tags: admob

I want to stop showing ads in my app if a user clicks any Interstitial Ad. Which listener will be good for this purpose ?

onAdClicked() is called when a click is recorded for an ad.

onAdLeftApplication() is called when an ad leaves the application (e.g., to go to the browser).

Answer (score 2):

interstitial ads are mostly used for leaving the app and see the ad content outside the app. So I will suggest onAdLeftApplication(). It will do the work same as onAdClick but will help to show ad content outside the app.

Comment: If it satisfied. why didn't this is accepted as answer?